# Extract duration in years and months from string and convert to months

Tags: r, date, time, substr

I have a string column with the length of a period, formated as `"xx years yy months"`. I want to express these periods in months only, i.e. 12 * number of years + number of months.

A small example:

```
x = c("2 years 5 months", "10 years 10 months")
```

Here the desired result is `2 * 12 + 5` = 29, and `10 * 12 + 10` = 130 respectively.

---

I tried the `substr` function, but I didn't manage to handle the fact that month and year may be either one or two digits.

```
12 * as.numeric(substr(x, 1, 2)) + as.numeric(substr(x, 6, 7)))
```

And then I tried the `sprintf` as below, but it didn't give the intended result.

```
sprintf("%1.0f", x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on your `substr` attempt: for months, you could define `start` and `stop` from the end of the string to avoid the issue with different start/stop positions depending on number of digits in month and year

```
as.integer(substr(x, 1, 2)) * 12 + as.integer(substr(x, nchar(x) - 8, nchar(x) - 6))
# [1]  29 130
```

Another non-regex alternative:

```
sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(v) sum(as.integer(v[c(1, 3)]) * c(12, 1)))
# [1]  29 130
```

Using `lubridate` convenience functions:

```
library(lubridate)
time_length(duration(x), unit = "months")
# [1]  29 130
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The Lubridate package helps me to tide the data.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions to extract the number of years and months this could be achieved like so:

```r
tomonths <- function(x) {
  sum(as.numeric(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+", x))[[1]]) * c(12, 1))  
}
tomonths("10 years 10 months")
#> [1] 130
```

For vectors you colud use e.g. `sapply(c("2 years 5 months", "10 years 10 months"), tomonths)`.

**EDIT**:  Following the comment by @thelatemail (Thanks!) a vectorized and more efficient approach would look like so:

```r
tomonths2 <- function(x) {
  sapply(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+", x)), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x) * c(12,1)) )  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a vector however. I think you have to loop over each value like `sapply(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+", x)), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x) * c(12,1)) )` to vectorise it.

Comment: Yep. You are right. But you could use e.g. `sapply(c("2 years 5 months", "10 years 10 months"), tomonths)`.

Comment: Indeed, but then you're running `regmatches` and `gregexpr` `length(x)` times unnecessarily.

Comment: @thelatemail. Thanks. Now I see your point. You are absoutely right. Actually, I overlooked the second part of your first comment.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me to solve the issue.